# Hide Author By-Line if After Certain Date

Tags: functions

I'm trying to use functions.php to hide the by-line on posts after a certain date. I'm using the following code but it isn't working. I think it's due to not properly grabbing the post date. How do I get the post date in functions.php?

```
// Hide By-Line

add_action('wp_head','my_head_css');
function my_head_css(){

$excludeDate = date("2021-06-02");
$postDate = get_the_date('Y-m-d');

if($postDate > $excludeDate){

    echo "<style> .entry-author {display:none !important;} </style>";
    
    }
}
```

Comment: What does `var_dump( $postDate );` tell you? That will let you know if, at least, you've got a valid date string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably getting the date as you expect, but the `>` is essentially a mathematical operator and you're trying to use it to compare two strings.

You can use [`strtotime()`](https://php.net/strtotime) to convert the dates to integers (# of seconds elapsed since `1970-01-01`), and compare those.

```
// Hide By-Line

add_action('wp_head','my_head_css');
function my_head_css(){

$excludeDate = date("2021-06-02");
$postDate = get_the_date('Y-m-d');

if( strtotime( $postDate ) > strtotime( $excludeDate ) ){

    echo "<style> .entry-author {display:none !important;} </style>";
    
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, having quickly read up on [PHP operators](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php), the `>` operator *should* be able to compare two date strings.